# Send data from ASP.NET pop up window to parent window using code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET pop up window. On click of the button in the pop up window there is some processing done on the server side and creates a complex object and then the child window closes. Now on closing the child window, i want to send this complex object to the parent window without using javascript. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Do not open a popup window to create this "complex object". Create it at server side and then render it in your response. Will come back to your original window.

There is nothing wrong in using javascipt where it does the task. Asp.net itself uses a lot of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need close interaction between the main page and the popup, do you want to keep it as a separate page? A better solution might be to include the controls for the popup within an asp:Panel, and use the [AJAX Modal Popup Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) to show it as a modal popup. This way, you have access to all the state of the main page on click of controls in the popup.